# Разные кодировки в href и value

Tags: кодировка, javascript, html, php, браузер

Добрый день! Столкнулся с неведомой фигнёй:

```
var_dump($login);
var_dump($pass);
echo "<a href ='$login $pass'>$login $pass</a>";
```

Выводит такой html:

```
string(8) "help"
string(8) "me!"
<a href="help���� me!�����">help me!</a>
```

Почему кракозябры только в href ?

**upg**: Код был разбит на кучу модулей, у вас бы браузер треснул если бы я все сразу вывалил! Вот образец, в точности моделирующий баг:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['login1']))
    {
        $data_in = $_POST['login1'];
        $master_pass = 'Blumgeshtulgents';
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC),MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        $data_cphiper =
        mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, md5($master_pass), $data_in, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        $data_out =
        mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, md5($master_pass), $data_cphiper, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    var_dump($data_out);
    echo "<a href ='http://syte.com/script.php?$data_out'>$data_out</a>";
}
else
{
echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="login1" placeholder="login"></input>
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Run</button>
</form>
<div id="result">
</div>
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var options = { 
            target:"#result",
            type:"post"
        };
        $("#myForm").ajaxForm(options); 
    }); 
</script> 
</html>
';
}
```

Comment: string(**8**) "help"   
ничего внезапного.

Comment: Согласен =) Но мне бы ответ на вопрос получить. Неправильно сформулировал заголовок, извините.

Comment: Откуда Вы берете значения этих переменных? (Кусок кода желателен)

Comment: о, там все сложно. Переменные берутся из формы, отправляются аяксом на сервер, шифруются-дешифруются mcrypt-ом, и вставляются обратно в див на исходную страницу. Но мне кажется, суть кроется в обработке html браузером

Comment: Значит Вам вряд ли смогут помочь, если только Ваш вопрос попадет в передачу «Битва экстрасенсов».  
Нужен код.

Comment: Обычно это делается при помощи https.

Comment: думается у вас заголовки ответа в неправильной кодировке, html часть съела как есть, а href надо же в url-rncoding переделать браузеру, он и не сообразил как.

Comment: @pilot114, оформите последний апдейт вопроса как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таки mcrypt виноват.

```
var_dump($_POST['login1']);
var_dump($data_out);
string(11) "tjdkjdkjedk" string(16) "tjdkjdkjedk"
```

с php.net: "It appears that mcrypt_decrypt pads the *RETURN STRING* with nulls ('\0') to fill out to n * blocksize."

Если делать так, то все ок:

```
rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(...),"\0");
```

eicto прав, в теле страницы нулл байты обычно игнорируются, но при попытке кодировать их в url они НЕ отбрасываются, что весьма странно. Всё, всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Ха, прикольный глюк. Тут даже гадание не поможет, если автор ничего не умалчивает. А автор умалчивает, т.к. кавычки отличаются:

```
echo "<a href ='$login $pass'>$login $pass</a>";
```

И

```
<a href="help���� me!�����">help me!</a>
```

А может просто у вас шаблонизатор автоматом заменяет кавычки и еще что-нибудь?

Comment: Два отличных замечания!
1. т.к. ответ вставляется аяксом динамически (просто "посмотреть исходный код" ничего не даст), пришлось копировать html из фаерфокс-консоли, там всегда кавычки двойные, по феншую =D
2. Я уже хотел было признать вас победителем в этой битве экстрасенсов, но увы, без шаблонов результат тот же. (вставил код - см. выше.)

Comment: @pilot114 при ajax запросе во вкладке "консоль" должна быть строчка об этом запросе. Посмотрите, как выглядит ответ в этой строчке.

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($_POST[login1])`.  
Так сразу станет ясно где искать ошибку- на клиенте или сервере.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<a href ='тут ссылка должна быть'>$login $pass</a>";
```

Comment: <a href="http://syte.com/script.php?help����&me!�����">
    help me!
</a>

Answer (score 0):

Проблема скорее всего там, где присваивается значение этим переменным. Попробуйте так:

```
$login = "help";
$pass = "me!";
echo "<a href ='$login $pass'>$login $pass</a>";
```

Что получается?

Comment: Пробовал, получается именно,то что вы думаете =) Ребята, вопрос не в том, почему бяка выводится, вопрос в том, почему одни и те же переменные в одной и той же строчке выводятся в двух разных кодировках. Добавил к вопросу теги 'html' и 'браузер'